# Input post not working onchage event CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My $this->input->post is not working when I changed the value of a dropdown menu (it dynamically display the record from db) it does not display any data and no errors too, but it's working fine if I assign a specific value to the where syntax.

Model:

```
    public function getData() {
            $where = $this->input->post('selected_holcode');

    $query = $this->db->get_where("hrms.holiday", "holcode = '$where'")->result();
    return $query;
```

Controller:

```
        public function getHolidaylist() {

        $data['record'] = $this->holiday_settings_model->getData();

        $this->load->view('maintainance/holiday_settings/holiday_list', $data);
        }
```

ajax (to display the record upon changing the dropdown menu)

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var controller = 'holiday_settings';
        var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';

        function load_data_ajax(type){
            $.ajax({
                'url' : base_url + '/' + controller + '/getHolidaylist',
                'type' : 'POST',
                'data' : {'type' : type},
                'success' : function(data){
                    var container = $('#holiday');
                    if(data){
                        container.html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_open('holiday_settings/getHolidaylist') ?> 
<div id="holiday"></div>


<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<label><strong>Year</strong></label>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;<label><strong>:</strong></label>
<select id="syear" onchange="load_data_ajax(1)">
    <?php
        for ($x=2015; $x>=2008; $x--) {?>
            <option><?php echo $x;?></option>
         <?php } ?> 

</select></br></br>

<select name="selected_holcode" onchange="load_data_ajax(1)">
    <option value="SPL">SPL</option>
    <option value="LGL">LGL</option>
    <option value="CMP">CMP</option>
</select></br></br>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but try this:

```
<select name="selected_holcode" onchange="load_data_ajax(this.value)">
```

instead of : load_data_ajax(1) 
 
or

```
onchange="load_data_ajax(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)
```

if your Dropdown was filled with dynamic data from DB

// EDIT
And what do you want to do if syear is changed?
since you call the same function? and you should set it like this:

```
 for ($x=2015; $x>=2008; $x--) {
       echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
      }
```

Now you can get your value to your onchange function like i already said

Comment: second one also for your <option> filled by for i think, havent tested yet

Comment: It basically filter the data in db, which shown in a table, if i change the year combobox it will display all the record pertaining to that year, if click the type of holiday (legal, special etc) it will again filtered with year and holiday type and goes vice versa

Comment: ok, i just dont see where you are submitting the year,...
and is the solution i postet working to you?
If yes, please accept the answer! if not show some more infos or error msg

Answer (score 0):

If you say that static value makes it work then your controller and model functions are working correctly I guess, Maybe you should try this:

```
onchange="load_data_ajax(1)" //instead of writing this
```

You should just pass the value like this:

```
onchange="load_data_ajax(this.value)"
```

Or as I see you are using `JQuery`, you can also do this:

```
<select name="selected_holcode" class="toggler" > <!-- Remove the onchange event and add a new class to the element -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ //on page load
    $(".toggler").on("change", function(){
       var value_to_send   = $(this).val(); //get the selectbox value here
       //your ajax call goes here 
    });
});
</script>
```